# Problem with blending in openGL (Color bar example)

Tags: opengl, blending

Can anyone give some clues as to why when I try to render the color bar quad below
[image]

It appears like this:
[image]

Here is my rendering code:

```
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_ONE, GL.GL_ZERO);
    gl.glBlendEquation(GL.GL_FUNC_ADD);

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    gl.glAlphaFunc(GL.GL_GREATER, 0.01f);

    // do the drawing...

    gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.glDisable(GL.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

I'm sure the solution is simple and I'm just having a brainfart but it's just one of those days!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Write this as a own answer and accept it, that's the way to mark self found solutions on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with RGBA getting swapped around when I imported the PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of blending are you trying to perform? To simply draw something without any color mixing or alpha channels you don't even have to play around with `GL_BLEND` or `GL_ALPHA_TEST` (leave both disabled). `GL_BLEND` is used to define how to add different "layers" of color (usually on how to apply alpha channels) while `GL_ALPHA_TEST` decides what alpha values to respect/ignore. Also check your vertex colors when rendering the quad (try to render a unicolor quad without texture, e.g. using magenta).

However looking at your images I'd guess you somehow disabled drawing to your red color channel (`glColorMask()`) - although there's yellow, which confuses me.

Comment: Since you're mostly asking a question, I don't think you should post this as an answer. But back on topic: the blue bar is also gone, which seems very weird.

Comment: Sorry guys. I've found the error and it was nothing to do with the blending. The RGBA values were getting messed up when I imported the PNG for some weird reason.